# Inlining two buttons - one inside a <form>, one outside

Tags: html, css

I have two buttons in an html template, one inside a form, the other outside of it. How do I style them via CSS such that they appear inline? Including `display: inline` in the second button doesn't work.

E.g. looking at the following snippet, how would `OK_1` and `OK_2` appear inline (using CSS only):

```html
<form action="some_url" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <!-- some form -->
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="OK_1">
</form>
<button>OK_2</button>
```

Comment: I have added the answer check it out

Comment: I would remove the button from the form element and use JavaScript to get the button to trigger the form.

Comment: @Dai the OP wanted to use css and html. Why use Java for something so simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY THIS:

Here is a runnable snippet.

```css
form input[type="submit"] {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
  margin:5px;
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 0;
  float: left;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<form action="some_url" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <!-- some form -->
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="OK_1">
</form>
<button class="button">OK_2</button>
```

You can customize all the styles above.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `display: inline-block` should do the trick.

```css
form {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form action="some_url" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <!-- some form -->
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="OK_1">
</form>
<button>OK_2</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply make the parent a flex container:

```css
body { display: flex; }
```

```html
<form action="some_url" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!-- some form -->
<input class="button" type="submit" value="OK_1">
</form>
<button>OK_2</button>
```

In a [***flex formatting context***](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers), flex items (the child elements in a flex container) line up in a row by default.

Answer (score 1):

You should give the form a class, so that other forms won't do that.

```css
form.inline_after {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<pre>↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
↓The form element is <span style="border: 4px dotted red; color: magenta; background-color: maroon;">in red</span>!↓
↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓</pre>
<form style="border: 4px dotted red; color: magenta; background-color: maroon;" class="inline_after" action="some_url" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <!-- some form -->
  <input style="margin: 5px; padding: 5px; color: magenta; background-color: maroon;" class="inline_after" class="button" type="submit" value="Button in the form!" onclick='alert("This is in the "+this.parentElement.nodeName+" element!")'>
</form>
<button style="padding: 5px;" onclick='alert("This is in the "+this.parentElement.nodeName+" element!")'>
  Button out of the form, but inline!
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make css for the form :

```css
form {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form action="some_url" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <!-- some form -->
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="OK_1">
</form>
<button>OK_2</button>
```

This is a short answer :)